# Certificate for this server is invalid with S3 and Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip, production

I'm working in a **Rails 5** application which is deployed by the moment on **Heroku**. I'm using **Postgrsql** for data storage, **Paperclip** to manage image uploads and **AWS S3** to store all the uploaded images.

To accomplish this I used this very detailed and useful [tutorial from Heroku dev](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3) which really help me a lot.

I use the same configuration for `development` env to be able to test it. Actually it works like a charm in dev.

When I deploy to Heroku and after running migrations, setting up ENV variables I create a new `Brochure` which accepts a cover image; and everything goes good. The images are stored correctly in AWS S3.

But when I render de image in a view I wit just don't work. I got the following errors in browsers console:

**Safari browser:**

```
Failed to load resource: The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “sponsors.matchxperience.s3.amazonaws.com” which could put your confidential information at risk.
```

[image]

**Chrom canary:**

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
```

[image]

I don't know what's the matter because in development environment everything works.

Can anybody help me out with this or any idea what's going on?

**production.rb** (the same in development.rb)

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # We’ll also need to specify the AWS configuration variables for the production Environment.
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
    storage: :s3,
    # s3_protocol: 'http',
    s3_credentials: {
      bucket: ENV.fetch('AWS_S3_BUCKET'),
      access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
      secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
      s3_region: ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION')
    }
  }
end
```

**brochure.rb**

```
class Brochure < ApplicationRecord
  # This method associates the attribute ":cover" with a file attachment
  has_attached_file :cover, styles: {
    card: '500x330#',
  }

  # Validate the attached image is image/jpg, image/png, etc
  validates_attachment_content_type :cover, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

**paperclip.rb** *at config/initializers/*

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
```

Comment: is your development url has https?

Comment: No, I'm working in `http://localhost:3000` and it works!

Comment: can you please add your paperclip configuration in your model?

Comment: That's all my config but I have solved it, thank you so much! But if you have something to share that may help someone else, please add the answer or the comment. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After searching and reading different sources for this error I found many different solutions for similar errors but no one seemed to be related with Rails 5 directly and sincerely I don't even though it has something to see with Ruby or Rails.

I was convinced it was something with the **AWS S3** server and I was right, ***I fixed it***. Finally reading the official documentation for [creating a new bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/CreatingaBucket.html) I realized that it was something ridiculously simple.

In the documentation it says we can use periods `.` and hyphens `-` in our bucket's name:

> Can contain lowercase letters, numbers, periods (.), and hyphens (-).
>
> Must start with a number or letter.
>
> Must be between 3 and 63 characters long.
>
> ...

So, I named my bucket as:

```
sponsors.matchxperience
```

Which was right written, ***BUT*** talking about server's **URLs** it may confuse the browser's requests to point to a different server and that was happening in my case. That's why I got that error.

**The solution**

Just create another bucket (*or renaming the actual one may function*) and copied all the content named as:

```
sponsors-matchxperience
```

And magically it just works fine in production on Heroku. I don't know what's going on with the AWS documentation but for me, that whats the error, periods `.` in my bucket's name.

I hope it could be useful for someone else.

Comment: *"When using virtual hosted–style buckets with SSL, the SSL wildcard certificate only matches buckets that do not contain periods. To work around this, use HTTP or write your own certificate verification logic. We recommend that you do not use periods (".") in bucket names.*" -- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html

Comment: Your solution is correct, but your diagnosis is a little off.  S3 was working correctly, but your browser (also working correctly) believed the *standard* security certificate to be invalid -- as indeed it technically was -- but not because S3 was confused or misbehaving.  An SSL/TLS cert for `*.example.com` is only valid for `*.example.com`, not `*.*.example.com`, since the `*` does not match dots for certificate validation purposes.  The limitation is in the way SSL wildcard certificates work, not in S3.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thank you so much for the explanation I just didn't see that part about creating a Bucket but yes it makes sense. Thanks for complementing the solution.